# Can you simplify this Boolean expression any farther?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I was working through a problem for a Computer Engineering course and i was given this logic function

```
F(A,B,C,D) = ~A~BC~D + ~AB~C~D + ~ABC~D + ABC~D
```

After factoring out BC~D from two of the terms and getting (~A + A) = 1 *(BC~D)
I got

```
F(A,B,C,D) = ~A(~BC~D + B~C~D) + BC~D
```

Is there any simplification that can be done any farther?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be simplified a little further. For convenience I’ll write $A'$ instead of $\sim\!\!A$.

$$\begin{align*}
A'B'CD'&+A'BC'D'+\color{red}{A'BCD'}+ABCD'\\
&=A'B'CD'+A'BC'D'+\color{red}{A'BCD'+A'BCD'}+ABCD'\\
&=(A'B'CD'+\color{red}{A'BCD'})+A'BC'D'+(\color{red}{A'BCD'}+ABCD')\\
&=A'(B'+B)CD'+A'BC'D'+(A'+A)BCD'\\
&=A'CD'+A'BC'D'+BCD'\\
&=(A'C+A'BC'+BC)D'\\
&=\big(A'(\color{red}C+BC')+BC\big)D'\\
&=\big(A'(\color{red}{C+BC}+BC')+BC\big)D'\\
&=\left(A'\big(C+B(C+C')\big)+BC\right)D'\\
&=\big(A'(C+B)+BC\big)D'\\
&=A'BD'+A'CD'+BCD'
\end{align*}$$